# HTML CSS responsive

Tags: php, html, css

When I make the window smaller, the navigation also adapts. And so it should. It works so far, but above a certain size the width is not filled anymore. The photo should complete my description.
[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFQFE.png)

PHP/HTML index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0;" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/stylesheet.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"> <!-- Icon für Navigation -->
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
require_once ('require/script/f_navigation.html');
require_once ('require/nagivation.html');
?>

<h1 class="home-h1-titel">Title</h1>

<!-- -------------------------------------- CONTAINER -------------------------------------- -->
<div class="home-container">
    <div class="border padding" >
        <h1 class="home-h1-container">Registrieren</h1>
        <p class="justify">A website (also written as web site) is a collection of web pages and related content that is identified by a common domain name and published on at least one web server.  </p>
        <button onclick="window.location.href = 'registrieren.html';">Registrieren</button>
    </div>
    <div class="border padding" >
        <h1 class="home-h1-container">Login</h1>
        <p class="justify">A website (also written as web site) is a collection of web pages and related content that is identified by a common domain name and published on at least one web server. </p>
        <button onclick="window.location.href = 'login.html';">Login</button>
</div>


<!-- -------------------------------------- FOOTER -------------------------------------- -->

<footer>
    <p>Footer<br>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

HTML navigation.html

```
<div class="navigation" id="navigation">
   <a href="index.php" class="right">Home</a>
   <a href="#placeholder" class="right">Placeholder 1</a>
   <a href="#placeholder">Placeholder 2</a>
   <a href="registrierung.html" class="right">Registrierung</a>
   <a href="login.html">Login</a>
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="f_navigation()">
       <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
   </a>
</div>
```

HTML f_navigation.html

```
<script>
   /* Wechseln Sie zwischen dem Hinzufügen und Entfernen der "responsive"-Klasse zur Navigation, wenn der Benutzer auf das Symbol klickt */
   function f_navigation()
   {
       var x = document.getElementById("navigation");
       if (x.className === "navigation") {
           x.className += " responsive";
       } else {
           x.className = "navigation";
       }
   }
</script>
```

CSS stylesheet.css

```
/*ALLGEMEIN*//*ALLGEMEIN*//*ALLGEMEIN*/
body
{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   font-family: Arial, serif;
}
footer
{
   position: fixed;
   width: 100%;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 3px;
   background-color: #282828;
   color: white;
   font-family: Arial, serif;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;

}

/********************************************************************************/
/* NAVIGATION*//* NAVIGATION*//* NAVIGATION*/
.navigation
{
   overflow: hidden;
   border-bottom: solid;
   border-color: white;
   border-width: 1px;
   background-color: #282828;
   width: 100%;
   text-align: right;
   /* position: fixed; MUSS DANN ENTFERNT WERDEN*/

}

/* Gestaltung der Links innerhalb der Navigationsleiste  */
.navigation a
{
   margin: 10px;
   display: inline-block;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 14px 16px;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-size: 18px;
   font-family: Arial, serif;
}

/* Ändert Style beim drüberfahren */
.navigation a:hover
{
}

/* Kennzeichnet die aktuelle Seite */
.navigation a.active
{
}

/* Hide the link that should open and close the navigation on small screens */
.navigation .icon
{
   display: none;
}

/* Wenn der Bildschirm weniger als 600 Pixel breit ist, wird die navigation zusammen genommen (Smartphone Ansicht) */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px)
{
   body
   {
       background-image: none;
       background-color: #a7a7e7;
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
       background-size: cover;
   }

   .navigation a
   {
       display: none;
       border: solid;
       border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255, 0);
   }
   .navigation a.icon
   {
       float: right;
       display: block;
   }

   .right
   {
       float: none;
   }


   .navigation.responsive /*Position der Navigation wenn das Icon gedrückt wurde*/
   {

   }
   .navigation.responsive a.icon /*Icon wenn gedrückt*/
   {
       position: absolute;
       right: 0;
       top: 0;
   }
   .navigation.responsive a
   {
       display: block;
   }
}
/********************************************************************************/
/*HOME*//*HOME*//*HOME*/
.home-container
{
   display: grid;
   grid-gap: 50px; /*Raster-Lücke*/
   justify-content: center;
   grid-template-columns:  repeat(2, minmax(200px, 1fr));
   margin-left: 10%;
   margin-right: 10%;

}

.home-h1-container
{
   margin: 5px;
   text-align: center;
   color: #282828;
   font-size: 30px;
   font-family: Arial, serif;
}

.home-h1-titel
{
   text-align: center;
   font-family: Arial, serif;

}
```

Can someone please help me?

Thank you so much!

Best regards

Comment: Look into "media queries". I see that you are using them. But you call it from javascript for some reason.

Comment: what do you mean by "media queries"? I can't find that in the code.

Comment: Media query: `@media screen and (max-width: 600px)`

Comment: I have tested it. The size, which I have indicated there, is not connected with it. Also the width in percent of the navigation is getting smaller and smaller.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing a couple of closing tags (`</p>` and `</div>`), otherwise your code works fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0;" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/stylesheet.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"> <!-- Icon für Navigation -->
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>


<script>
   /* Wechseln Sie zwischen dem Hinzufügen und Entfernen der "responsive"-Klasse zur Navigation, wenn der Benutzer auf das Symbol klickt */
   function f_navigation()
   {
       var x = document.getElementById("navigation");
       if (x.className === "navigation") {
           x.className += " responsive";
       } else {
           x.className = "navigation";
       }
   }
</script>
<div class="navigation" id="navigation">
   <a href="index.php" class="right">Home</a>
   <a href="#placeholder" class="right">Placeholder 1</a>
   <a href="#placeholder">Placeholder 2</a>
   <a href="registrierung.html" class="right">Registrierung</a>
   <a href="login.html">Login</a>
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="f_navigation()">
       <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
   </a>
</div>


<h1 class="home-h1-titel">Title</h1>

<!-- -------------------------------------- CONTAINER -------------------------------------- -->
<div class="home-container">
    <div class="border padding" >
        <h1 class="home-h1-container">Registrieren</h1>
        <p class="justify">A website (also written as web site) is a collection of web pages and related content that is identified by a common domain name and published on at least one web server.  </p>
        <button onclick="window.location.href = 'registrieren.html';">Registrieren</button>
    </div>
    <div class="border padding" >
        <h1 class="home-h1-container">Login</h1>
        <p class="justify">A website (also written as web site) is a collection of web pages and related content that is identified by a common domain name and published on at least one web server. </p>
        <button onclick="window.location.href = 'login.html';">Login</button>
</div>
</div>


<!-- -------------------------------------- FOOTER -------------------------------------- -->

<footer>
<p>Footer<br></p>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Here's the corrected version: https://jsfiddle.net/zrcwh3mn/

Comment: Thank you very much. I can see that it works for you. I copied my code to https://jsfiddle.net/zrcwh3mn/ and ran it. It works. But why doesn't it work when I access the site with Chrome or Edge? I have deleted browser data.

Comment: I'm not sure. You aren't using any browser specific css. Do you think you can host it over public network using something like 'ngrok'? Or maybe Github pages or any other free service so that I can have a look?